# How Can Users Authorize Revolut Businees API To Access The Account

Tags: api, security

I'm trying to integrate Revolut business API in my website where my employees can login and see their balance and transaction (which i manage by my revolut business account),But there is a problem regarding making requests to their [API](https://developer.revolut.com/docs/manage-accounts/get-started/make-your-firs-api-request). 
  The user must authorize the App to access the API each time they login, is there any way to automate the process plus not storing anything related to the API for security reasons. 
**Note** : im currently storing the token and refresh token in a JSON file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am currently trying something similar for a customer and I really don't like to store the accessToken & refreshToken on the server.

My process is the following:

The platform owner consent the application via the revolut url.
On successful redirect I then exchange the authorization_code to an accessToken and refreshToken to perform future requests.
But I it's really a bad practice to store these tokens on the server or database.

Is there an alternative way, e.g. using a client secret?

Comment: thank you for your comment.
We currently still looking for better solutions, but we couldnt find anything better than storing the refresh token in the database.
its really pain to work with their API